# Are UIEventSubtypeRemoteControl* "switches" fair game for use in non-media applications?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

The app store review guidelines states...

> Apps that alter the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume
>   Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, will be rejected

But Apple has opened up the following switches as UIEvents (notably there are no Volume events or Ring/Silent events included). Implicitly it would seem that these are not "standard switches" although they show up as "Now Playing" controls, earbud mic controls or AVRCP switches.

UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPlay
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPause
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlStop
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingBackward
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingBackward
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlBeginSeekingForward
   UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlEndSeekingForward

Is the developer free (as in avoiding app store rejection) to make novel use of these events, say, using the TogglePlayPause event outside of the context of actually playing or pausing media content? Does anyone here have experience with an app being rejected because of non-traditional use of these remote control events?